# value in for loop doesn't return outside the loop

Tags: python, for-loop, append

Here is my code:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,5))
t = np.linspace(0, 700, 700)
#print(len(signal[0, :]))
chi_sqr_tab = []
def expo_func(t, a, t0, tau0, tau1, c):
    S = a * (1 - np.exp(-(t - t0)/tau0)) * np.exp(-(t - t0)/tau1) + c
    return S
for i in range (len(signal[:, 0])):
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(expo_func, t ,signal[i, :], maxfev=9600)
    plt.plot(t, expo_func(t,*popt),linestyle='-')
    #print(len(popt))
    for j in range (4):
        chi_sqr = (signal[i,j] - popt[j-1]) / popt[j-1]
    chi_sqr_sum = np.sum(chi_sqr)
    #print(chi_sqr)
    chi_sqr_tab.append(chi_sqr_sum)
    #print(chi_sqr_tab)
print(len(chi_sqr_tab))
```

I tried to print out the value in the for loop, and it did print out the values! But when I tried to print outside the loop, it printed nothing? Why did it happen? I mean,I thought .append is used to adding value to the list outside the loop, right? It should work as my experience (it worked in all my another codes)

Comment: `for j in range (4):
        chi_sqr = (signal[i,j] - popt[j-1]) / popt[j-1]` are you sure of this? `chi_sqr` never defined before it effectively becomes `chi_sqr = (signal[i,3] - popt[3-1]) / popt[3-1]`. Also you are printing length not the elements `print(len(chi_sqr_tab))`

Comment: What are the behaviours of the two print locations? Can you edit to include the locations and their outputs?

Comment: I did print the element and length , both of them printed out nothing

Comment: wdym by include locations and output? @jhso

Comment: I'm guessing the loop just hasn't finished. Add a waitbar via `tqdm` maybe?

Comment: I mean,the problem is that when I printed out in the loop,it did so! and the list was appended one by one without any problem, but when I printed out outside of the loop,it printed nothing '-'

Comment: @ShlomiF maybe,let me try again

Comment: hmm,nope, Jupiter lab ended the process and I still saw nothing

Comment: Yeah, @Epsi95's point is still valid. You're not incrementing or appending chi_sqr in your code (in the inner for loop), so it will be a singular value. Fix this first, but it's weird that it's not printing ANYTHING. Is this in the same Jupyter cell?

Comment: yes,in the same one '-'